# FadeIn/out appended div after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I simply store my divs in an array and delete them from it once I've appended them.

I now want to fadein and fadeout every div, after a delay.

Here is a snippet :

```js
var arr = $(".notification");

function display(){
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    $("#result").append(arr.eq(rand))
    arr = arr.not(":eq("+rand+")")
    if(arr.length>0) createRandomInterval();
}



function createRandomInterval() {
    setTimeout(display, 500 + Math.random() * 4000);
}
createRandomInterval()
```

```css
.notification {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <div class="notification">object 1</div>
  <div class="notification">object 2</div>
  <div class="notification">object 3</div>
  <div class="notification">object 4</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I've tried to add

```
.fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
```

to my function. But this just fades all divs in and out at once.

What I try is, that every div, at the moment, when it appends, is faded in and will be faded out, after 3 seconds.

Here is my fiddle without the animation: https://jsfiddle.net/0ydo3kvd/

Comment: Where are you using `.fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);`? Do you need [this](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/sm6dLwLf/)?

Comment: I don't understand why can't you make a snippet if you can make a fiddle?  Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set at first in the result div your `.notification` to hidden `display:none` , then after adding each one to the result div , you just set display to flex , then chain fade ,delay , and fadeOut .

See below working snippet :

```js
var arr = $(".notification");

function display(){
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    let notfi = arr.eq(rand);
    $("#result").append(notfi);
    notfi.css("display","flex").fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
    arr = arr.not(":eq("+rand+")")
    
    if(arr.length>0) createRandomInterval();
}



function createRandomInterval() {
    setTimeout(display, 500 + Math.random() * 4000);
}
createRandomInterval()
```

```css
.notification {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#result .notification {
  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <div class="notification">object 1</div>
  <div class="notification">object 2</div>
  <div class="notification">object 3</div>
  <div class="notification">object 4</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much!